# Reading data from file with javascript + cordova

Tags: javascript, file-io, cordova

I'm trying to understand how file reading/writing works with cordova/phonegap but it seems I'm not succeding. I have implemented the "Full example" [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) on my computer and runned it with Ripple emulator (and "TEMPORARY" file system request because it seems ripple doesn't like "PERSISTENT"). I created a file "readme.txt" which I wanted the program to read, and I filled it with some text. The program seems to work executing all the commands, yet when it comes to the instructions:

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
```

the output is just "*Read as data URL*" and blank for the "result", even if the file is not blank. I don't understand if it is the normal behaviour or I'm missing something.

Things get worse when I zip the program folder and send it to phoegap build. In this case the program fails to read the file. Maybe it is not correct to send the readme.txt file inside the zipped folder where i put the code for phonegap build? Where should the file be?

Comment: why you test application in Ripple emulator..check in android sdk or real device..File Api works fine in devices or android emulator